# Commit Process Through Command Line - Repo Not Updating

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I am learning how to use GitHub. I have it downloaded on my Mac desktop, and have an account online.

I created a practice folder on my computer 'test4' with one file in it called 'index4.html'.

Now when initialize git, I don't see the git folder created in my directory. When I commit changes, nothing is added to my github accounts. Here is my process via the command line, I think I am missing a step.

Terminal:

```
cd test4
git init
git add index4.html
git commit -m "comment"
git push origin master
git clone https://github.com/ibagha/test_test.git
```

There is nothing showing up in the repository I made. If anyone can let me know what I could be doing wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git is a *distributed* version control system. This means you have a full copy of the repository on your computer and a separate full copy of the repository on Github. When you run `git commit`, you are committing to your local repository. You need to `git push` to send that change back to Github.

You don't see the git folder after you initialize git because it is actually called `.git` and would be hidden by default on most operating systems. Try `ls -a` to show it. But you don't actually have to interact with that folder directly at all.

Your commands are somewhat mixed up. You shouldn't need to do both `git init` and `git clone`. Also, `git clone` should be the first command you run. If you run `git push` before `git clone`, git won't know where to push your changes to (it doesn't know about the remote Github repository yet).

Try this:

```
cd new_test
git clone https://github.com/ibagha/test_test.git ./
echo "foobar" >> index4.html # Make a change
git status # Not necessary - shows you what's up
git add index4.html
git status # Look what changed
git commit -m "comment"
git status # Look what changed
git push # You only have one remote and one branch. Don't need to specify.
```

Extra info:

- To show all remotes, `git remote`
- To show your branch (master) and the upstream remote it is tracking, run `git branch -vv`
- You can make as many commits locally as you want before running `git push`. `git push` will send all the commits on your current branch to Github if Github doesn't already know about them, effectively "syncing" Github with your local repository.

Comment: oh ok, the hidden .git file makes sense. I tried git push and see nothing on the desktop version or github. how do i specify which repository the file goes to?

Comment: perfect, thanks. i didnt know the clone git clone https://github.com/ibagha/test_test.git ./ has the "./" at the end

Comment: The format of that command is `git clone <repository> [<directory>]`. The directory is optional, and by default, it will clone into a directory with the same name as the git repository (in your case, `test_test`). I just wanted to put it in the current directory, so I did `./`. But you can do any directory you want. For example, `git clone https://github.com/ibagha/test_test.git /tmp/foobar`.